# CAShapeLayer with shaded area below

Tags: ios6, uiview, core-animation, quartz-2d, cashapelayer

I am drawing a graph line using CAShapeLayer now I want to fill the area below of that line created by CAShapeLayer, ?I have tried CAShapeLayer shadow, gradient but it doesn't work, Please guide me the correct way to achieve this. My code is below:

```
//1. Create bezier path from first point to second.
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:firstPoint];
[path addLineToPoint:secondPoint];


//2. Create a shape layer for above created path.
myLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
myLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
myLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
myLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
myLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
myLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
myLayer.path = path.CGPath;
myLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
myLayer.shadowRadius = 12;

myLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
myLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
myLayer.shadowRadius = 50;
myLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

[drawnLayersArray addObject:myLayer];
[self.scroll.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to do and the results you are currently getting?

Comment: I am successfully able to draw the lines over my scrollview, I am drawing the lines using CAShapeLayer, but now i want to fill the whole below area with a color.